# macro NAME expansion as string c/C++

Tags: c++, c

I want use the NAME of the macro inside the macro expansion as string.

Example:

```
#define DEBUG_TEST(a, ...) printf("DEBUG_TEST::%s (%d) : " a, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Want to change to something that doesn't need the "DEBUG_TEST" anymore in the exapansion, but something like:

```
#define DEBUG_TEST(a, ...) printf(__MACRO__ "::%s (%d) : " a, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Of course in my example **__*MACRO*__** dosen't exist...

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want in place of `__MACRO__`?

Comment: There is no such feature in any preprocessor I ever come across.

Comment: @user93353 : I just want something that replaces __MACRO__ with a construct that inserts the name of the macro (DEBUG_TEST) in the example. (I used __MACRO__ to show a familiar construct like __FUNCTION__).

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is not possible. My suggestion would be to create another macro that takes the name of the macro as argument. Then use this macro in your other macroses.